# How to set product name attribute as unique in magento

Tags: magento, attributes

I'm using a search box that shows a list of product names in a drop-down list.

When the user selects one of the product name and clicks search, the page will be redirected to the product associated to that name.

The problem here is: if the product contains more than one similar name, we will fail to redirect the user to the correct product. That's whey Iwould like to add an unique product name.

I wasn't able to set it as `unique` in admin's `Manage attribute` tab.

I tried to change it via database by changing its value from 0 to 1 in `eav_attribute` table, but it does not make any sense.

So, how can I add `unique` option to the `product name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE 'eav_attribute' SET is_unique = 1 WHERE `entity_type_id` = 4 and  `attribute_code` like 'name'
```

Its the best way.

Comment: Yeah got it! thanks a lot Guerra fixed correctly. Actually i did a big mistake instead of updating `entity_type_id=4` i was updated for `entity_type_id=3`. :-)